# How to create a custom Progress Bar?

Tags: android, material-design, progress-bar

I am looking for a way to implement a custom Progress bar but I wanna change the left and right side as diamond like this  [Progress Bar Custom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqh3S.png) Does anyone one how can I implement a drawable file with those "corners" or stuff like that, does not matter if is something programatically, because right now I implement a drawable file like

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/quantum_yellow"
            android:centerColor="@color/quantum_yellow"
            android:centerY="100.0"
            android:endColor="@color/quantum_yellow"
            android:angle="270"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#007A00"
                android:centerColor="#007A00"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#06101d"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

but this code just change the color and change the round corners but I want the corner like this image[Diamond corners progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB6l5.png)

I appreciate if anyone have an idea about this!